# Failed to Run Foreach Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-8

I have a code and I'm still getting the result that I want expect. I've tried exploring the references related to the error I got. But I haven't been able to solve it.
The code is like this:

```
public function getVoteSend($prov, $city, $distr)
{
    try {
        $ccount     = CreCount::where('status', 1);
        $acount     = AneCount::where('status', 1);

        if ($prov && $city && $distr) {
            $ccount->where([
                ['province', '=', $prov],
                ['district', '=', $city],
                ['subdistrict', '=', $distr]
            ]);
            $acount->where([
                ['province', '=', $prov],
                ['district', '=', $city],
                ['subdistrict', '=', $distr]
            ]);
        } elseif ($prov && $city) {
            $ccount->where([
                ['province', '=', $prov],
                ['district', '=', $city],
            ]);
            $acount->where([
                ['province', '=', $prov],
                ['district', '=', $city],
            ]);
        } else {
            $ccount->where('province', $prov);
            $acount->where('province', $prov);
        }

        $ccount     = $ccount->get();
        $acount     = $acount->get();

        $cvillage   = $ccount->pluck('village')->toArray();
        $cnumber    = $ccount->pluck('number')->toArray();

        $avillage   = $acount->pluck('village')->toArray();
        $anumber    = $acount->pluck('no_tps')->toArray();

        $region = Region::where('id_prov', 11)
                ->orWhere('id_kota', 1101)
                ->orWhere('id_kec', 110101)
                ->get();

                $unverif = 0;
                $verif   = 0;
            
                foreach ($region as $key => $val) {
                    if (in_array($val->id_kec, $cvillage) && in_array($val->number, $cnumber)) {
                        $unverif += 1;
                    }
            
                    if (in_array($val->id_kec, $avillage) && in_array($val->number, $anumber)) {
                        $verif += 1;
                    }
            
                $total = $unverif + $verif;
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        $message = "Data Not Found.";
        return $this->sendError($message, 400, $th->getMessage());
    }

    return $total;
}
```

For the DB structures:

CreCount table and AneCount table :

```
id int(11)
kode int(11)
nama varchar(12)
number int(3)
id_prov varchar(11)
id_kab varchar(11)
id_dist varchar(11)
id_kec varchar(11)
is_valid tinyint(1)
```

Region table:

```
id varchar(255)
kode varchar(255)
number varchar(255)
prov varchar(255)
distr varchar(255)
subdist varchar(255)
village varchar(255)
is_valid tinyint(1)
```

The expected result is that if there is data entered into the database with the value `is_valid = 0` and `is_valid = 1`, the value will increase by `1`.

But when I try to hit on Postman, the result is always `0`.
Can anyone help me to solve this? Please.